# How do you deal with sequences of IDisposable using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable, dispose, idisposable

What's the best approach to call `Dispose()` on the elements of a sequence?

Suppose there's something like:

```
IEnumerable<string> locations = ...
var streams = locations.Select ( a => new FileStream ( a , FileMode.Open ) );
var notEmptyStreams = streams.Where ( a => a.Length > 0 );
//from this point on only `notEmptyStreams` will be used/visible
var firstBytes = notEmptyStreams.Select ( a => a.ReadByte () );
var average = firstBytes.Average ();
```

How do you dispose `FileStream` instances (*as soon as they're no longer needed*) while maintaining *concise* code?

---

To clarify: this is not an actual piece of code, those lines are methods across a set of classes, and `FileStream` type is also just an example.

---

Is doing something along the lines of:

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> Where<TSource> (
            this IEnumerable<TSource> source ,
            Func<TSource , bool> predicate
        )
        where TSource : IDisposable {
    foreach ( var item in source ) {
        if ( predicate ( item ) ) {
            yield return item;
        }
        else {
            item.Dispose ();
        }
    }
}
```

might be a good idea?

---

Alternatively: do you always solve a very specific scenario with regards to `IEnumerable<IDisposable>` without trying to generalize? Is it so because having it is an untypical situation? Do you design around having it in the first place? If so, how?

Comment: what I don't like about this question is that without a concrete scenario that you are trying to achieve, all the effort in the answers might be completely off. It makes for an interesting discussion, but it might be far from addressing a real solution.

Comment: A specialized solution for a specific scenario most likely would be trivial, as answers so far show. I'm interested if there's a more generalized approach to handing IEnumerable<IDisposable>. Creating a monad around IDisposable is a step in that direction, I think.

Comment: I don't think your method example is a good idea. LINQ methods shouldn't have side effects on enumerated values, and yours have a pretty serious one.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you turn the `streams` variable into an `Array` or a `List`, because enumerating through it a second time will (if I'm not mistaken) create new copies of the streams.

```
var streams = locations.Select(a => new FileStream(a, FileMode.Open)).ToList();
// dispose right away of those you won't need
foreach (FileStream stream in streams.Where(a => a.Length == 0))
    stream.Dispose();

var notEmptyStreams = streams.Where(a => a.Length > 0);
// the rest of your code here

foreach (FileStream stream in notEmptyStreams)
    stream.Dispose();
```

**EDIT** For these constraints, maybe LINQ isn't the best tool around. Maybe you could get away with a simple `foreach` loop?

```
var streams = locations.Select(a => new FileStream(a, FileMode.Open));
int count = 0;
int sum = 0;
foreach (FileStream stream in streams) using (stream)
{
    if (stream.Length == 0) continue;
    count++;
    sum += stream.ReadByte();
}
int average = sum / count;
```

Comment: +1: I think you are right about the temporary copy without the ToArray: I hadn't noticed that.

Comment: Good point about iterating a second time. That's exactly why I'm looking for a pattern where instances would get disposed once they've been used, thus at the time of the second iteration the “old” instances would no longer exist (or at least not hold onto resources).

Comment: @chase If this is your concern, as I said, turning the sequence into an array will prevent further evaluations of the selector, so you won't get more than one copy of each stream.

Comment: true, but the sequence has a lot of elements, each holding onto several handles, and large memory blocks. Generators are the only option, arrays or lists won't do. And which is why I'd rather dispose them sooner than later.

Comment: @chase Then maybe LINQ isn't the tool you're looking for. There are sacrifices to do if you want to achieve this kind of performance. What about running a simple foreach?

Answer (score 3):

I would write a method, say, `AsDisposableCollection` that returns a wrapped `IEnumerable` which also implements `IDisposable`, so that you can use the usual `using` pattern. This is a bit more work (implementation of the method), but you need that only once and then you can use the method nicely (as often as you need):

```
using(var streams = locations.Select(a => new FileStream(a, FileMode.Open))
                             .AsDisposableCollection()) {
  // ...
}
```

The implementation would look roughly like this (it is not complete - just to show the idea):

```
class DisposableCollection<T> : IDisposable, IEnumerable<T> 
                                where T : IDisposable {
  IEnumerable<T> en; // Wrapped enumerable
  List<T> garbage;   // To keep generated objects

  public DisposableCollection(IEnumerable<T> en) {
    this.en = en;
    this.garbage = new List<T>();
  }
  // Enumerates over all the elements and stores generated
  // elements in a list of garbage (to be disposed)
  public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() { 
    foreach(var o in en) { 
      garbage.Add(o);
      yield return o;
    }
  }
  // Dispose all elements that were generated so far...
  public Dispose() {
    foreach(var o in garbage) o.Dispose();
  }
}
```

Comment: I've been thinking about that. But suppose a method returns DisposableCollection<>. This means you either forgo the ability to filter the result (or you lose the “disposability”), or lose the fluency of LINQ, or have to implement your own .Where(), etc. methods, making them return DisposableCollection<> as well.

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution is the following:

```
List<Stream> streams = locations
    .Select(a => new FileStream(a, FileMode.Open))
    .ToList();

try
{
    // Use the streams.
}
finally
{
    foreach (IDisposable stream in streams)
        stream.Dispose();
}
```

Note that even with this you could in theory still fail to close a stream if one of the FileStream constructors fails after others have already been constructed. To fix that you need to be more careful constructing the inital list:

```
List<Stream> streams = new List<Stream>();
try
{
    foreach (string location in locations)
    {
        streams.Add(new FileStream(location, FileMode.Open));
    }

    // Use the streams.
}
finally { /* same as before */ }
```

It's a lot of code and it's not concise like you wanted but if you want to be sure that all your streams are being closed, even when there are exceptions, then you should do this.

If you want something more LINQ-like you might want to read this article by Marc Gravell:

- [SelectMany; combining IDisposable and LINQ](http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2009/11/selectmany-combining-idisposable-and.html)

Comment: This assumes there's a specific location in code where you can put that. Also it doesn't dispose empty streams as soon as it's determined they're empty and no longer needed.

Comment: I'd also just like to say that if an exception is thrown from "stream.Dispose()" (NullRefException for instance), this would also prevent streams from being closed, no?

Answer (score 1):

## Description

I've come up with a general solution to the problem :)
One of the things that were important to me was that everything is correctly disposed, even if I don't iterate the whole enumeration, which is the case when I use methods like `FirstOrDefault` (which I do quite often).

So I came up with a custom Enumerator which handles all the disposing. All you have to do is call the `AsDisposeableEnumerable` which does all the magic for you.

```
GetMy.Disposeables()
    .AsDisposeableEnumerable() // <-- all the magic is injected here
    .Skip(5)
    .where(i => i > 1024)
    .Select(i => new {myNumber = i})
    .FirstOrDefault()
```

*Please note that this does not work for infinite enumerations.*

## The Code

1. My custom IEnumerable

   ```
   public class DisposeableEnumerable<T> : IEnumerable<T> where T : System.IDisposable
   {
       private readonly IEnumerable<T> _enumerable;

       public DisposeableEnumerable(IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
       {
           _enumerable = enumerable;
       }

       public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
       {
           return new DisposeableEnumerator<T>(_enumerable.GetEnumerator());
       }

       IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
       {
           return GetEnumerator();
       }
   }
   ```
2. My custom IEnumerator

   ```
   public class DisposeableEnumerator<T> : IEnumerator<T> where T : System.IDisposable
   {
       readonly List<T> toBeDisposed = new List<T>();

       private readonly IEnumerator<T> _enumerator;

       public DisposeableEnumerator(IEnumerator<T> enumerator)
       {
           _enumerator = enumerator;
       }

       public void Dispose()
       {
           // dispose the remaining disposeables
           while (_enumerator.MoveNext()) {
               T current = _enumerator.Current;
               current.Dispose();
           }

           // dispose the provided disposeables
           foreach (T disposeable in toBeDisposed) {
               disposeable.Dispose();
           }

           // dispose the internal enumerator
           _enumerator.Dispose();
       }

       public bool MoveNext()
       {
           bool result = _enumerator.MoveNext();

           if (result) {
               toBeDisposed.Add(_enumerator.Current);
           }

           return result;
       }

       public void Reset()
       {
           _enumerator.Reset();
       }

       public T Current
       {
           get
           {
               return _enumerator.Current;
           }
       }

       object IEnumerator.Current
       {
           get { return Current; }
       }
   }
   ```
3. A fancy extension method to make things look good

   ```
   public static class IDisposeableEnumerableExtensions
   {
       /// <summary>
       /// Wraps the given IEnumarable into a DisposeableEnumerable which ensures that all the disposeables are disposed correctly
       /// </summary>
       /// <typeparam name="T">The IDisposeable type</typeparam>
       /// <param name="enumerable">The enumerable to ensure disposing the elements of</param>
       /// <returns></returns>
       public static DisposeableEnumerable<T> AsDisposeableEnumerable<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable) where T : System.IDisposable
       {
           return new DisposeableEnumerable<T>(enumerable);
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Using code from https://lostechies.com/keithdahlby/2009/07/23/using-idisposables-with-linq/, you can turn your query into the following:

```
(
    from location in locations
    from stream in new FileStream(location, FileMode.Open).Use()
    where stream.Length > 0
    select stream.ReadByte()).Average()
```

You will need the following extension method:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Use<T>(this T obj) where T : IDisposable
{
    try
    {
        yield return obj;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (obj != null)
            obj.Dispose();
    }
}
```

This will properly dispose all the streams that you create, whether or not they are empty.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple wrapper that allows you to dispose any `IEnumerable` with `using` (to retain the collection type rather than casting as `IEnumerable`, we would need nested generic parameter types [which C# does not seem to support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3230569/how-to-do-nested-generic-classes-if-thats-the-appropriate-name-in-csharp)):

```
public static class DisposableEnumerableExtensions {
    public static DisposableEnumerable<T> AsDisposable<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable) where T : IDisposable {
        return new DisposableEnumerable<T>(enumerable);
    }
}

public class DisposableEnumerable<T> : IDisposable where T : IDisposable {
    public IEnumerable<T> Enumerable { get; }

    public DisposableEnumerable(IEnumerable<T> enumerable) {
        this.Enumerable = enumerable;
    }

    public void Dispose() {
        foreach (var o in this.Enumerable) o.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
using (var processes = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses().AsDisposable()) {
    foreach (var p in processes.Enumerable) {
        Console.Write(p.Id);
    }
}
```