# Generic type arguments inside generic constraints

Tags: c#, generics

I want to create a class that has a generic type argument which has a constraints to be a subclass of another generic class.

Example:

```
public class SomeGeneric<T> where T : new()
{
    T CreateItem() => new T();
}
```

This class I want to create. Note: I do not want client of this class to specify the inner type argument twice:

```
public class TheClass<TGeneric> where TGeneric : SomeGeneric<T>, new()
{
    public T Item {get; private set;}
    public void TheClass
    {
        var instance = new TGeneric(); // this is possible because of the new() restriction
        Item = instance.CreateItem();
    }
}
```

This could then be used as follows:

```
class AnotherClass
{

}

class Client : TheClass<SomeGeneric<AnotherClass>>
{
    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        var theInstanceOfAnotherClass = this.Item;
        // Do stuff with it
    }
}
```

As far as I can tell, this is not possible since it complains on this line that `T` is not known:

```
public class TheClass<TGeneric> where TGeneric : SomeGeneric<T>, new()
```

The workaround would be to do as follows:

```
public class TheClass<T, TGeneric> where TGeneric : SomeGeneric<T>, new()
```

But that would mean that the client has to do this:

```
public class Client : TheClass<AnotherClass, SomeGeneric<AnotherClass>>
```

I want to avoid duplicating the inner type argument. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is possible. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3230569/how-to-do-nested-generic-classes-if-thats-the-appropriate-name-in-csharp) addresses the same situation.

This blurb from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6cyy67b.aspx) also states that it's not allowed, unlike in C++. I'm not sure if there's a reason for this limitation.

> In C#, a generic type parameter cannot itself be a generic, although constructed types can be used as generics. C++ does allow template parameters.

I think you will have to rework your class in some way to use a generic `object`, or else just live with the duplicate type argument.

Answer (score -2):

Does this work or even resemble what you want?

```
public SomeClass<TGeneric<T>> where TGeneric<T> : SomeGeneric<T>
```

Comment: No, `TGeneric` is a type argument not a generic type itself, but yes, that is what I'd like to achieve

Comment: I don't think there's a way to do what you want without declaring `T` first. Generic type arguments are sort of like function arguments; you have to declare them before you can use them.